# Network Requirements For WASD Game Server

Tags: networking

I wonder whether it is possible to build a single game server that would be capable of handling a lot of players in a game that uses WASD controls (as we know, WASD generates way more data on the network than point-and-click). I am not talking about server-side code performance (because I know it could easily do that) but I wonder whether network would allow you to do this. And I am not talking about many game servers serving different *rooms* or stuff like that because it's basically a different story.

As it would be a game, it would not benefit from a CDN and would be forced to rely on a single server. I guess it would be capable if the players were located around the server (for example in USA or EU only) but would it be playable on the other side of the globe, for example Australia?

Plus, I wonder, how long does it take for a signal to travel from EU to US or around the globe? What would be the latency? I have heard some people reporting latency being more than a second or so, which would be unplayable with WASD.

Answer (score 1):

Your game server doesn't need to receive every keypress event.  That's what the client's for.  Your client handles and responds to the input events by for example updating your player's location.  That new location data is what's sent to the server, often as a delta from the last location.

In short, here's a basic sequence:

- Player presses W
- Client software handles W, and moves the player's entity forward
- Client software packages up the player's entity state and transmits it to the server
- The server applies the change in state for the player to its internal state

  - This is where you should check for things like "Is this movement feasible?"
- Server replicates the new entity state to all other clients
- Those clients integrate the new entity state to update their internal state
- Rinse
- Repeat

If you're interested in cribbing from some shipped source, check out [how Doom 3 manages things](https://github.com/TTimo/doom3.gpl/blob/master/neo/game/Game_network.cpp).